# Using Team Foundation Server 2012 without Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I'm overseeing a VSS to TFS 2012 migration at my shop and have hit a snag: the "report guy" uses Crystal Reports (don't know the version, sorry) and doesn't have Visual Studio.  Under VSS that wasn't an issue because there is a stand-alone client for VSS... but there is no such animal for TFS.  What do I need to give the report guy so he can use TFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply [install Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656), which offers a standalone installation if you do not have a version of Visual Studio installed.

Technically, this is installing the Visual Studio shell, but does not install any of the development tools.  So your "report guy" will be able to use the Team Explorer view, Source Control Editor, Work Item Editors and other TFS features without having to install (or license) the full Visual Studio experience.

Comment: Is it possible to use VS2010 with TFS 2012 ?